Why can we use conservation of momentum when deriving the thrust formula?
I am completely new to physics, but I do have a little mathematical background. So I decided to read Taylor's classical mechanics, becase I heard it was good for building intuition. Indeed, this book is not the most mathematically rigorous text out there, but I accepted this going into it.
However, when it came to the discussion of thrust, the author uses conservation of momentum to derive the formula (or at least the fact that the change in total momentum is equal to the net external force). However when deriving the conservation of momentum he assumes that the mass of a particle doesn't change, but the whole point of thrust is that it only arises when a mass of an object is changing.
Now I know that the mass of the rocket doesn't change, it's because of the fact that fuel is being ejected, that the mass of the rocket + mass of fuel in rocket is changing. But I don't see exactly how we can apply the conservation of momentu, in this scenario.
Before talking about thrust he gives an illustrative example, where you find yourself in the middle of a perfectly frictionless surface, and you have to find your way to the edge. Now if you throw your boot for example then because your thrown boot now has momentum, and the total momentum has to stay zero you also gain momentum, just in the opposite direction. Here I see no issue since we can always treat the boot like a separate mass, and it just so happens that in the beginning both you and the boot have zero velocity.
Once we start talking about thrust, it seem like a similar thing happens at every "instant".
Which is just not well formulated for me, because in order for the conservation of momentum to hold, the masses of objects have to stay constant, but what are the basic objects in this scenario? The rocket and infinitely many infinitely small bits of fuel with infinitely small mass?
Hopefully you can see that someone with a more mathematical background can be quite sceptical about stuff like this. So is my understanding correct? And is there maybe a more mathematically sound way to prove the thrust formula?

Mass of rocket does change, because it includes fuel mass also by definition. Doesn't change so called "dry mass" ,- empty rocket mass.

"Here I see no issue since we can always treat the boot like a separate mass, and it just so happens that in the beginning both you and the boot have zero velocity". But you could just as well say that when the boot is thrown the person loses mass. How is that different than the rocket losing mass that exits it?

We can imagine the rocket and the fuel to be just very many particles of constant mass. Then conservation of momentum applies to this set of particles. If we know some subset gets momentum in one direction (hot combustion products), the other subset (the solid rocket with unburned fuel) has to get the opposite momentum.


because in order for the conservation of momentum to hold, the masses
of objects have to stay constant,

I believe this is the root of your confusion.
It is the total mass of the entire isolated system that cannot change in order for momentum to be conserved, not the mass of the individual components of the system, which can change.
In the case of the rocket-fuel system, the total mass of the system (rocket + fuel) does not change. The fuel (or more precisely, the combustion products of the fuel) separates from the rocket acquiring momentum in one direction whilst the solid components of the rocket and fuel remaining in the rocket, acquires an equal amount of momentum in the opposite direction for conservation of momentum.
As another example, consider a stick of dynamite initially at "rest" somewhere in space free of exposure to any external forces. The dynamite explodes into thousands of fragments moving in various directions, with each fragment acquiring momentum based on its mass and velocity. Since the dynamite (system) is isolated, the sum of the momenta of its particles is zero, and the sum of the masses of the individual particles equals the original mass of the stick of dynamite. The kinetic energy of the system of particles is equal to chemical potential energy orignally stored in the dynamite before ignition.
Hope this helps.

Thank you, indeed this is helpful. I have thought about something similar, but I wasn't sure if this reasoning was correct. I just don't see why the author starts his proof by summing the momentum of each particle in the system, to get the total momentum, and then taking the derivative to get the total force. Because if mass is changing, I don't see how the derivative of the sum would become the sum of all forces.

@GergőKelemen I’d have to see the whole proof in context to fully understand the author’s reasoning, rather than guess. Unfortunately I don’t have a copy of Taylor

You need to write integral form of balance equations of physical quantities for an open system, namely for a geometrical volume $V$, with boundary $\partial V$ whose points have velocity $\mathbf{u}_b$,

mass balance:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{V_t} \rho \, + \oint_{\partial V_t} \rho (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} = 0$$

momentum balance:
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int_{V_t} \rho \mathbf{u} \, + \oint_{\partial V_t} \rho \mathbf{u} (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u}_b) \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} = \int_{V_t} \rho \mathbf{g} + \oint_{\partial V_t} \mathbf{t}_n \ ,$$


being $V_t$ the geometric volume whose boundary is the closed surface built as the union of the solid external frame of the rocket and the outflow surface of the nozzle, $\partial V_t = S_{solid} \cup S_{out}$.
We'll made the reasonable assumptions that:

solid walls have no mass flux through them,
the total mass of the system in $V_t$ is the sum of the solid frame $m_s$ take as constant and the mass of the contained fluid $m_{f,in}$
the fluid inside the rocket moves approximately with the known velocity of the rocket $\mathbf{u} \sim \mathbf{u}_{b} = \mathbf{U}$
the velocity of the fluid at the outflow is known, $\mathbf{u}|_{S_{out}} = \mathbf{u}_o$
density is known

Thus, integral balance equations read

mass
$$0 = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( m_s + m_{f,in} \right) + \Phi_{S_{out}}(m_f) = 0$$
$$\dot{m_f} = - \Phi_{S_{out}}(m_f) \ .$$

momentum
$$\begin{aligned}
    \dfrac{d}{dt} ( m_s \mathbf{U} + m_{f,in} \mathbf{U} ) & = - \mathbf{u}_{out} \Phi_{S_{out}}(m_f) = \mathbf{F}_V + \mathbf{F}_{\partial V} \\
    (m_s + m_{f,in}) \dot{\mathbf{U}} + \dot{m}_{f,in} \mathbf{U} & = \dot{m}_{f,in} \mathbf{u}_{out} + \mathbf{F}_V + \mathbf{F}_{\partial V}
  \end{aligned}$$
that can be written as
$$( m_s + m_{f,in}(t) )\dot{\mathbf{U}} = \dot{m}_{f,in} (\mathbf{u}_{out} - \mathbf{U}) + \mathbf{F}_V + \mathbf{F}_{\partial V} \ ,$$
where the LHS is $m_{tot}(t) \mathbf{A}$, with $\mathbf{A}$ the acceleration of the system, and the RHS collect the sources of acceleration, namely the flux of momentum through $S_{out}$, volume forces $\mathbf{F}_V$ (as an example, it could contain weight, $\mathbf{F}_V = (m_s + m_{f,in}) \mathbf{g}$) and surface forces $\mathbf{F}_{\partial V}$ due to surface stresses on the boundary of the volume $\partial V$, both stresses on solid surface and stresses in fluids at the section of the nozzle.
In order to make a simple example, let's assume the motion of the rocket along $z$-axis, and neglect $\mathbf{F}_{\partial V}$. The velocity of the rocket is $\mathbf{U} = U \hat{\mathbf{z}}$, the velocity of the fluid at $S_{out}$ is $\mathbf{u}_{out} = u_{out} \hat{\mathbf{z}}$, with $u_{out} < U$ in order to generate thrust, $\mathbf{g} = - g \hat{\mathbf{z}}$; the time derivative of the contained fluid $\dot{m}_{f,in}$ equals the opposite of the mass flux across $S_{out}$, $- \dot{m}_{f,in} = \Phi_{S_out}(m_f) > 0$, usually a design parameter.
The equation of motion thus reads
$$m_{tot}(t) \dot U = \underbrace{\underbrace{\Phi_{S_{out}}(m_f)}_{>0} \underbrace{(U - u_{out})}_{>0}}_{T} - m_{tot}f(t) g \ ,$$
where the definition of thrust $T = \Phi_{S_{out}}(m_f) (U-u_{out})$ is introduced.



Although there a few physics related concepts, which I haven't heard of, I am very thankful that you have given me a more rigorous approach. I will definitely look into it.

Feel free to ask

The two concepts I haven't heard of were the mass balance and inertial balance, but after looking into it, I think I understand them decently.

Mass balance is just Lavoisier's law: in classical mechanics you can't create or destroy mass: if the mass contained in a volume changes, it must be due to a flux of mass that you put inside or remove from it. Momentum balance equation is just 2-nd principle of Newton mechanics for open systems: you need to add the effect of the flux of momentum (what produces thrust here) to the external forces as the causes that can make momentum of a system change. Hope it helped

As a general rule$-$when thinking about "infinitesimal" quantities in physics, I find it helpful to ask "what would approximately be true, if these infinitesimal quantities were actually just small and finite?"
On a certain level, I don't think about the ejection of mass as a continuous process$-$I think about it as a discrete process where at discrete time intervals, a small but finite mass is ejected. I can then apply momentum conservation at each of those time intervals. This is nice, because you can think of the "fuel ejection" as many small "boot ejections".
(As it happens, the world is in fact made of discrete chunks known as "atoms", but this isn't actually the point I'm trying to make.)
Say the rocket has mass $m$ before one of these ejections, and mass $(m + \Delta m)$ afterwards, so $\Delta m < 0$. Suppose its velocity changes by $\Delta v > 0$ during the ejection. Also say the fuel is ejected with speed $v_\text{ext} > 0$ relative to the rocket. After applying momentum conservation and some algebra, we can write down the equation:
$$
(m + \Delta m)\Delta v = v_\text{ex} (-\Delta m)
$$
Hopefully that makes conceptual sense$-$the logic really is the same as the boot on the ice rink.
You could even get a fairly accurate model for the rocket, if you repeated this process many times. But that summation would not be very elegant. It would require introducing indexed quantities $v_i$ and $m_i$ and $\Delta v_i$, and computing lots of cross terms, and the answer would slightly depend on how small $\Delta m$ is. But that should still give you a sense of what the rocket is "really doing".
(Perhaps, if you computed it at the level of atoms, it would be even more accurate than doing it with calculus.)
The trick then, is to find out how to turn this into a nice continuous process. Consider again the above equation. The terms $\Delta m$ and $\Delta v$ are small, but the product $\Delta m \Delta v$ is really small. If $m$ and $v$ are about equal to $1$, and $\Delta m$ and $\Delta v$ are about equal to $0.01$, then the product is $0.0001$. If you sum the process $100$ times, then the $\Delta m$ and $\Delta v$ terms will add up to $0.01 \times 100 = 1$, which is significant compared to the original mass and velocity. But the cross terms will sum up to $0.0001 \times 100 = 0.01$, which does not really make much difference to the final answer. (Nevermind the fact that these quantities are changing$-$this is just a rough argument about the magnitudes involved.)
So then, if we ask what is approximately true, we have the new equation
$$
m \Delta v \simeq - v_\text{ex} \Delta m
$$
This should approach the "true continuous process" as $\Delta m$ decreases, so writing it in differential form, we can say
$$
m dv = -v_\text{ex} dm
$$
And applying the usual methods of calculus, we get the logarithmic solution
$$
v - v_0 = v_\text{ex} \ln(m_0/m)
$$
where we split the integration constant into the physically interpretable bits $v_0$ and $m_0$.

Thank you. I believe Taylor was trying to make a similar argument, but you explained it very intuitively.
